# Using clang-11 to cross compile for aarch64-linux-gnu on x86-64 error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, cross-compiling, arm64

I am trying to use clang-11 to cross compile a c++ file to aarch-linux-gnu, from my host machine which is x86-64.

Here's the command :
`clang-11 -v -target aarch64-linux-gnu -B/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib -march=armv8.5-a+memtag -fsanitize=memtag test_mte.cpp -static`

But, I run into this error:

`In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/stdlib.h:36: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstdlib:41:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found #include <bits/c++config.h>`

I have installed the packages `gcc-multilib g++-multilib binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu libc6-arm64-cross libc6-dev-arm64-cross crossbuild-essential-arm64 gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`

How can I resolve this error?

**Full Output:**
Here's the full output of the clang-11 command:

`Debian clang version 11.0.1-2~bpo10+1

Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8

Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8

Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8

Candidate multilib: .;@m64

Selected multilib: .;@m64

"/usr/lib/llvm-11/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test_mte.cpp -static-define -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +mte -target-abi aapcs -fallow-half-argum
ents-and-returns -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-11/lib/clang/11.0.1 -internal-isystem /usr/bi
n/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../..
/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/c++/8 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/aarch64-linux-gnu/c++/8
-internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -in
ternal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-11/lib/clang/11.0.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdepreca
ted-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/aditi712/mte_Stuff -ferror-limit 19 -fsanitize=memtag -fno-signed-char -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-ex
ceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/test_mte-836487.o -x c++ test_mte.cpp

clang -cc1 version 11.0.1 based upon LLVM 11.0.1 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/aarch64-linux-gnu/c++/8"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/aarch64-linux-gnu/c++/8"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"

#include "..." search starts here:

#include <...> search starts here:

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/backward

/usr/local/include

/usr/lib/llvm-11/lib/clang/11.0.1/include

/usr/include

End of search list.
In file included from test_mte.cpp:7:

In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/stdlib.h:36:

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstdlib:41:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found

#include <bits/c++config.h>`

Comment: Do NOT use stuff in bits in your own files, if that's what you're doing. Use the standard header files you need.

Comment: I'm including stdlib.h in my code, which includes bits/c++config.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps there's a compiler setup problem, then.

Comment: You're compiling as C++? If so, `#include <cstdlib>` would be recommended. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I tried changing the include to <cstdlib>, but am getting the same error: '/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/cstdlib:41:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found                 #include <bits/c++config.h>'

Comment: Sorry. It was worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that clang is asking some gcc about system include paths, and this process fails (for some reason), leading to inclusion of host headers.

Here is a solution that helped me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/947954/wrong-default-include-directories-for-clang-cross-compile

Basically you provide all system includes on your own. In our case (arm64), for me this boiled down to these flags:

```
-nostdinc++ 
-cxx-isystem /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/10/`
-cxx-isystem /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/10/aarch64-linux-gnu/
-isystem /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include
```